# Mechanize: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, mechanize-python

I have tried to write the following code, I am trying to write a code in `Python 3.7` that just opens a web browser and the website fed to it in the `Command Line`:

**Example.py**

```
import sys

from mechanize import Browser
browser = Browser()

browser.set_handle_equiv(True)
browser.set_handle_gzip(True)
browser.set_handle_redirect(True)
browser.set_handle_referer(True)
browser.set_handle_robots(False)

# pretend you are a real browser
browser.addheaders = [('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36')]

listOfSites = sys.argv[1:]
for i in listOfSites:
    browser.open(i)
```

I have entered the following command in the `cmd`:

```
python Example.py https://www.google.com
```

And I have the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Example.py", line 19, in <module>
    browser.open(i)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 253, in open
    return self._mech_open(url_or_request, data, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 283, in _mech_open
    response = UserAgentBase.open(self, request, data)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_opener.py", line 188, in open
    req = meth(req)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_urllib2_fork.py", line 1104, in do_request_
    for name, value in self.parent.addheaders:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I am very new to `Python`. This is my first code here. I am stuck with the above traceback but haven't found the solution yet. I have searched for a lot of questions on SO community as well but they didn't seem to help. What should I do next?

**UPDATE:**

As suggested by @Jean-François-Fabre, in his answer, I have added `'User-agent'` to the header, now there is no traceback, but still there is an issue where my link cannot be opened in the browser.

Here is how the `addheader` looks like now:

```
browser.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go :)

```
import sys
from mechanize import Browser, Request


browser = Browser()

browser.set_handle_equiv(True)
browser.set_handle_gzip(True)
browser.set_handle_redirect(True)
browser.set_handle_referer(True)
browser.set_handle_robots(False)

# setup your header, add anything you want
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1', 'Referer': 'http://whateveritis.com'}


url_list = sys.argv[1:]
for url in url_list:
    request = Request(url=url, data=None, headers=header)
    response = browser.open(request)
    print(response.read())
    response.close()
```

Comment: I am having an error as "`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib2`"

Comment: what is `urllib2` here?

Comment: I am still having this error "`NameError: name 'urllib2' is not defined`"

Comment: I have used your updated code, still I am getting an error

Comment: "`NameError: name 'urllib2' is not defined`" this is the error

Comment: Do I need to install the `Request` package manually for this?

Comment: Updated with just `mechanize` library only

Comment: Thanks man, it worked too, but the answer that I was seeking, was the best by @hyperTrashPanda, but your updates were the best suited, +1 for that

Answer (score 3):

I have just found out a way around to this issue even if the above issue still exists. I am posting this only to let the readers know that we can do it this way too:

Instead of using the `mechanize` package, we can use the `webbrowser` package and write the following python code in the **Example.py**:

```
import webbrowser
import sys

#This is an upgrade suggested by @Jean-François Fabre
listOfSites = sys.argv[1:]

for i in listOfSites:
    webbrowser.open_new_tab(i)
```

Then we can run this python code by executing the following command in the terminal/command prompt:

```
python Example.py https://www.google.com https://www.bing.com
```

*This command mentioned above in the example will open two sites at a time. One is Google and the other is Bing*

Comment: This is the _correct_ solution as `mechanize` does not open a graphical user interface (AFAIK).

Comment: @ThomasHesse are you sure, because when I was trying to do the above implementation, one of the methods out of a bunch of others was to use `Mechanize`. And the code worked for sometime, but the next day when I tried to run the code, this issue happened, not sure what happened in a single night.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know `mechanize` at all, but the traceback and variable names (and some googling) can help.

You're initializing `addheaders` with a list of strings. Some other examples (ex: [Mechanize Python and addheader method - how do I know the newest headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31636341/mechanize-python-and-addheader-method-how-do-i-know-the-newest-headers)) show a list of `tuple`s, which seem to match the traceback. Ex:

```
browser.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
```

so it unpacks properly into `name` and `value` in loop

```
for name, value in whatever.addheaders:
```

You have to add the `'User-agent'` property name (you can pass other less common parameters than the browser name)

Comment: I have added 'User-agent' to the header, now the code runs fine, there is no traceback, but still the link is not opened in the browser.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this upgrade _listOfSites = sys.argv[1:]_

Comment: that probably doesn't help much for your issue

Comment: yopur question has +3 score now, If it's not answered, you can place a bounty in a few. It could need it to attract more readers. Note: my answer would not be eligible (and it doesn't need to be)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I am thinking of doing since, no one is answering right for the mechanize issue.

Comment: I think it's not answerable as is, but people can comment and ask for precisions later. Even 50 attracts a lot of people

Comment: yeah, but no one is doing that either, so the last option is a bounty. Although I have figured a way around this issue by using webbrowser library

Comment: By using `webbrowser.open_new_tab(i)` instead of `browser.open(i)`

Comment: maybe you can answer your own question then, with this solution

Comment: Yeah let me try that

Comment: I have just answered my own question

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to answer your question in parts:

- You're correct in adding "Browser Headers". Many servers might outright drop your connection as it's a definite sign of being crawled by a bot.
- `mechanize` as stated by the [docs](https://pypi.org/project/mechanize/) *"is a tool for programmatic web browsing"*.
  This means it is primarily used to crawl webpages, parse their contents, fill forms, click on things, send requests, but not using a "real" web browser, with parts such as CSS rendering. For example you cannot open a page and take a screenshot, as there's not something "rendered", and to achieve this you would need to save the page, and render it using another solution.
- If this suits you needs, check [headless browsers](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers) as a technology, there are *a lot* of them. In the Python ecosystem, other than `mechanize`, I'd check ["headless chromium"](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/headless/README.md), as ["phantomjs"](http://phantomjs.org/) is unfortunately discontinued.

But if I understand correctly, you need the actual web browser to open up with the webpage, right? For this reason, you actually need, well, a browser in your system to take care of that!

#### Case 1 : Use your native system's browser

Find out where your browser's executable lies in your system. For example, my Firefox executable lies in `"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"` and [add it to your PATH](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10).

As you're using Windows, use the start menu to navigate to `Advanced System Settings --> Advanced --> Environment Variables`, and add the path above to your `PATH` variable.

If you're using Linux `export PATH=$PATH:"/path/to/your/browser"` will take care of things.

Then, your code can run as simply as

```py
import subprocess
import sys

listOfSites = sys.argv[1:]
links = ""
for i in listOfSites:
    links += "-new-tab " + i
print(links)
subprocess.run(["firefox", links])
```

Firefox will open new windows, one for each of the links you have provided.

#### Case 2 : Use selenium

Then comes [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/), which in my opinion is the most mature solution to browser-related problems, and what most people use. I've used it in a production setting with very good results. It provides both the UI/frontend of a browser that renders the webpages, but also allows you to programmatically work with these webpages.

It needs some setup, (for example, if you're using Firefox, you'll need to download the `geckodriver` executable from their [releases page](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases), and then add it your `PATH` variable again.

Then you define your webdriver, spawn one for each of the websites you need to visit, and `get` the webpage. You can also take screenshot, as a proof that the page has been rendered correctly.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import sys

listOfSites = sys.argv[1:]
for i in listOfSites:
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get('http://'+i)
    driver.save_screenshot(i+'-screenshot.png')

# When you're finished
# driver.quit()
```

I've tested both of these code snippets, and they work as expected. Please let me know how all these sound, and if you need any more additional information..! ^^

Comment: I am just trying to create a script to surf the net, its not a dependency to use actual web browser, and Selenium is something that is mostly used by Automation Testers, I primarily need to focus on python as this something that I need to learn as best as possible for AI development. Can you please elaborate more how can I avoid an actual browser but still surf the net?

Comment: What does "surf the net" consist of? If you want to render and display the webpages, you *need* a browser, and I don't think you can replace its functionality, (or at least I don't know of a way).. If you want to just crawl from URL to URL and obtain the HTML only, `mechanize` or `webbrowser` are good to go, but I'd recommend also looking at the `requests` package, but you *won't* have a graphical user interface. Selenium is indeed primarily used for automation testing, but it's quite simple to grasp, and I think has its uses for other tasks in the industry.

Comment: Its okay, I dont need a graphical interface, all I need is to search and get the search result and process form data, what data should be passed and what should be the value that I need from that query.. that's what I am hoping for in _surf the net_

Comment: How can I use `mechanize / webbrowser / requests` package for this, since I am very new to python. Is there any link or API that I refer to for the reference of these packages?

Comment: Ah, okay, now I understand your requirements in a better way, thanks for the clarification!  For your specific use case, the best thing IMO, is indeed `mechanize`. Keep the [official docs](https://mechanize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/browser_api.html) nearby, as well as [these](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/mechanize/browsing-in-python-with-mechanize) [and](http://toddhayton.com/2014/12/08/form-handling-with-mechanize-and-beautifulsoup/) [these](http://www.open-bigdata.com/data-mining-web-python-mechanize-tutorial/) tutorials, and start hacking away! StackOverflow is also here for questions

Comment: Final thing, if you *need* to load and execute javascript in your webpages, Selenium is a must, but for now, I think you're free to ignore it.

Comment: I dont need to load Javascript into the webpage, I am just trying to create a bot that can surf the net, lets see what else I can explore in this while making this. I am seriously excited to learn about AI and how can I make one using Python.

Comment: Have fun in doing so! Sentiment Analysis in webpages is a good idea that can be explored, and could be straightforward if you have the parsed data. [Alexa's Top 500](https://www.alexa.com/topsites) list is a nice starting point.

Comment: is there any way to debug python script in notepad++, or can you suggest me some other python editor that can help me debug the code too?

Comment: Notepad++ (and most text editors) don't provide debugging capabilities AFAIK, so you'd have to either use `pdb`, `gdb` to debug from the command line, or a proper Python IDE such as Pycharm, Eclipse, Spyder, you have lots to choose from.

Answer (score -1):

Same as above. Guess I didn't read all the answers before digging in. LOL

```
import sys
import webbrowser

from mechanize import Browser
browser = Browser()

browser.set_handle_equiv(True)
browser.set_handle_gzip(True)
browser.set_handle_redirect(True)
browser.set_handle_referer(True)
browser.set_handle_robots(False)

# pretend you are a real browser
browser.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36')]

listOfSites = sys.argv[1:]
for i in listOfSites:
    webbrowser.open(i)
```

Comment: This didn't help. Otherwise, it wont be a question